# How to flag a misspelled tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[This edit request](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5277371) "correcting" a correctly-spelled tag to an incorrect spelling on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258753/autocloseable-resource-leak-warning-for-factory-created-instances) made me think it would be better to correct the tag rather than persist in tagging things with the wrong spelling for the sake of consistency. There are only 11 questions with the misspelled tag, so it would not be too onerous to edit/retag them all, but rather than do that, can a tag simply be renamed by someone with sufficient rep? The incorrect tag name is `autoclosable`; the correct one is `autocloseable`.

Comment: All 11 questions seem to be linked to [tag:autocloseable] right now, that's the correct tag, isn't it?

Comment: I think someone uttered an appropriate incantation...

Comment: It looks like [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/510036/qix) went ahead and retagged them a few minutes before you asked this question.

Comment: Is it preferred to retag like that than alter the tag itself?

Comment: When it's for such a low amount of questions, yes. I think once you approach 100, it's better to post here like you just did.

Comment: @Synchro: Only moderator can rename tags, and it's usually best to only bother them with task that are unfeasible to do yourself. So retagging a small amount of questions is best done manually.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything in such cases.

There are zero questions tagged with the misspelled tag - an automated (daily) process cleans unused tags.

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around! The misspelled one has 11 uses, the correctly spelled one has none!

Comment: What? You saying that [tag:autoclosable] is correct?

Comment: @Oded see the comments on the question, someone retagged all questions while the OP was writing this question, hence the confusion :)

Comment: @Stijn - fair enough. All I could see was things looking fine...

Comment: On a somewhat related note, somebody's created the tag `gogland` for referring to JetBrain's new IDE for the Go language. However, the correct name is actually `goland`. I did not see a way to correct it.