# Synonymise [gogland] and [goland] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Referring the [announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2017/11/02/announcing-goland-former-gogland-eap-18-final-product-name-templates-support-and-more/) by Jet Brains and a recent comment in old [SO Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265402), can [gogland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gogland) and [goland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goland) be synonymised?

The announcement is present here in a screenshot:

[image]